# How many solution are possible for $x,y,z \in \{0,1,2,3,4,...\} , 50x+25y+10z=2000$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

$$x,y,z \in \{0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}, 50x+25y+10z=2000$$ I have no clue to this form of equation . But I can solve by two variable . 
  This is multiple choice question $$703\\716\\820\\861$$ Can anyone help me?

Comment: first divide by $5$ , then use G.C.D.

Comment: How can i use g.c.d ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\quad{50x+25y+10z=2000\div5\\10x+5y+2z=400\\\implies y=2y'\\z=5z' }$$now $$\quad{x,y',z' \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5...\}\\10x+5(2y')+2(5z')=400\\x+y'+z'=40\\\begin{pmatrix}
 40+3-1 \\
 3-1 
 \end{pmatrix} =\frac{42\times 41}{2}=861}$$